# How to use GetOptions to detect trailing strings?

Tags: perl, getopt, getopt-long

I am absolutely new to Perl and I am trying to figure out a problem with Perl script parsing script arguments.

I have the following Perl script called sample-perl.pl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my $source_address;
my $dest_address;

GetOptions('from=s' => \$source_address,
           'to=s' => \$dest_address) or die "Usage: $0 --from NAME --to NAME\n";
if ($source_address) {
    say $source_address;
}

if ($dest_address) {
    say $dest_address;
}
```

And if I use a command like (**where I forgot to enter the second option**):

```
perl sample-perl.pl --from nyc lon
Output will be: nyc
```

How can I enforce that if there is an additional string at the end, it is detected and an error is displayed instead?

Solution:

adding this will help my case at least:

```
if(@ARGV){
    //throw error
}
```

Comment: Check `scalar @ARGV` ? If `@ARGV > 0` there are (nonoption) arguments not picked up by `GetOptions()` on the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `GetOptions`, check for any remaining command line options in the `@ARGV` array.  This assumes that all unexpected arguments will generate an error:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my $source_address;
my $dest_address;

GetOptions('from=s' => \$source_address,
           'to=s' => \$dest_address) or die "Usage: $0 --from NAME --to NAME\n";

@ARGV and die "Error: unexpected args: @ARGV";

if ($source_address) {
    say $source_address;
}

if ($dest_address) {
    say $dest_address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was busy answered and I see it is now answered, just some additional info.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my $source_address;
my $dest_address;

GetOptions('from=s' => \$source_address,
       'to=s' => \$dest_address) or die "Usage: $0 --from NAME --to NAME\n";

@ARGV and die "To many arguments after --from or --to : @ARGV ";

if ($source_address) {
say $source_address;
} else {
say "Error: No Source specified"; #Check to see if --from is actually specified, else print error.
}

if ($dest_address) {
say $dest_address;
} else {
say "Error: No destination specified"; #Check to see if --to is actually specified, else print error.
}
```

so in short

Comment: but the usage specifically says must be or `die "Usage: $0 --from NAME --to NAME\n";` which tells me you need both options. like for instance calculating distance from and to.

Comment: Your answer is correct and is marked as such, I just added the additional stuff which made sense to me :)